# Why is my ant builder building an outdated version of one of my dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am working on two java projects. Project A uses Project B as a referenced library. I need to export my code from both of these projects in a single jarfile. To do this, I created a `lib/` folder in Project A and automatically export Project B to that folder. I then automatically export project A with a buildfile like this one, such that all jarfiles in the `lib/` folder are included in the final jar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="projectA" default="makejar" basedir=".">
    <target name="makejar" description="Create a jar for the project">
        <jar destfile="/destination/file/path/projectA.jar">
            <fileset dir="bin/"></fileset>
            <zipgroupfileset dir="./lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        </jar>
   </target>
</project>
```

This has been working fine for months. A few hours ago, however, this began exporting only an outdated version of B. I decompiled the code in the `lib/` folder and determined that the B export is indeed up to date. However, my decompiled code in the destination file includes an out of date version of B.

I have tried:

- restarting eclipse
- cleaning/rebuilding all projects
- deleting the existing jarfile at the destination
- deleting B from `lib/`, re-exporting B, and reconfiguring my build path for A
- Window --> Show View --> Problems

How do I go about diagnosing this problem? Bonus points if you have a better way of managing dependencies so that I won't have to sink ~30% of my development time into stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that anyone else encounters this, I'll post the solution I found here. I think this was the wrong place to ask this question, but I was getting desperate.

In my question, I give only a heavily simplified version of my setup. In reality, I have 10-some projects, many of which depend on each other.

In this case, the issue was that Project C, which was also part of A's `lib/` folder, also depended on Project B. However, I had C closed in Eclipse, so C wasn't being auto-exported. My ant builder, for some reason, allowed C's reference of B to override A's reference to B at compile time.